# How to integrate a graph in Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout (msagl) to a particular form so that in I can drag the graph as it is a Button or textBox

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, msagl

I am new to using C# and trying to create a Windows Form App project.

**Form1.Designer.cs** is [here](https://codeshare.io/1YNlZ7) and below is the **Form1.cs** (the form that I intend to create)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LearnCSharp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            /* --Upper bound of Block-- A */
            System.Windows.Forms.Form form = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
            //create a viewer object 
            Microsoft.Msagl.GraphViewerGdi.GViewer viewer = new Microsoft.Msagl.GraphViewerGdi.GViewer();
            //create a graph object 
            Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Graph graph = new Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Graph("graph");
            //create the graph content 
            graph.AddEdge("A", "B");
            graph.AddEdge("B", "C");
            graph.AddEdge("A", "C").Attr.Color = Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Color.Green;
            graph.FindNode("A").Attr.FillColor = Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
            graph.FindNode("B").Attr.FillColor = Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Color.MistyRose;
            Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Node c = graph.FindNode("C");
            c.Attr.FillColor = Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Color.PaleGreen;
            c.Attr.Shape = Microsoft.Msagl.Drawing.Shape.Diamond;
            //bind the graph to the viewer 
            viewer.Graph = graph;
            //associate the viewer with the form 
            form.SuspendLayout();
            viewer.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            form.Controls.Add(viewer);
            form.ResumeLayout();
            //show the form 
            form.ShowDialog();
            /* --Lower bound of Block-- A */
        }
    }
}
```

**Block A** is a template that I get from [MSAGL code sample](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/microsoft-automatic-graph-layout/code-samples/)

When I build the solution and run the .exe, the **Form1** and the **MSAGL graph** ***show consecutively/separately*** (The **MSAGL graph** is not an element in **Form1**).

---

**My question is:**
Here is the windows form that I want to create so that the MSAGL graph can be the element of Form1 that I want to create in this green area. (and if possible can be dragged/modified the properties as it is a button or any element in the form). How to implement that?
[image: Form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's because inside the constructor for Form1, you create a totally new and separate form:
`System.Windows.Forms.Form form = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();`
and display it:
`form.ShowDialog();`

Instead, just add the graph to Form1:
`this.Controls.Add(viewer);`
and since your building all this and adding it in the constructor, no need to SuspendLayout/ResumeLayout.

So once again, to recap what you should do, delete this line:

`System.Windows.Forms.Form form = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();`

and any lines that reference `form`, and then add this line:

`this.Controls.Add(viewer);`

and leave all other lines as is.

Comment: But then, how to drag the position or modify the graph position? Because it overwrites another button

Comment: So to obtain something like what you have in that screenshot, you'll want to fill the form with a docked TableLayoutPanel. This should be the root-most control. All other controls will be nested inside this control. This will let you split up the form into two columns (or however many row/columns you want) like shown. In each column, you'll need to place a Panel control which will contain the controls that appear in each column. In the right column's panel, you'll place the graph: this.panel1.Controls.Add(viewer).